# I Deleted all migrations and re created database but "Import Error : No module named 'django.db.migrations"

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

I am currently using Django 1.10.7 and Python 3.5. I think I seriously screwed everything up in my django project. I wanted to wipe my MySQL database, so I created another db but I was reading that I need to delete all migrations in my database(so I deleted the db and created another with a different name) and deleted the migration files in my app. I followed a guide with said to run in terminal:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

After this, when I try to run makemigrations, I get error:

```
"ImportError: no module named 'django.db.migrations.exceptions'.
```

I couldn't find anyone else with this problem and honestly I'm about to create an entirely new virtualenv and set up everything again from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include virtual environment in your project and the command `find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete` delete all file in django/db/migrations : [image].

The the simplest way is reinstall django or recreate virtual environment.

Comment: I was in my virtualenv within my project when I used those commands.

Comment: Yes,this is why the error "ImportError: no module named `'django.db.migrations.exceptions' `occur, find commands to ignore your environment folder or delete your makemigrations file manual,the person wrote those commands fail to anticipate this is someone put env in the project directory(just like you and me)

Comment: Oh i see, okay so If i reinstall the same version of django on my current virtualenv, would that fix the issue?I dont want to have to create an entirely new virtual env.